# How can I restart TeamViewer with a button click on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, teamviewer

I'm developing a GUI and I need for the GUI to be able to restart Teamviewer if it crashes.

I tried doing this using the kernel commands on a Team Viewer "Cheat Sheet"

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.title(string="TeamViewerRebootButton")
root.geometry("200x200")

def closePop_upCallback():
    None

def teamviewerReboot():
    rebooting = tk.Toplevel(master=root)
    label = tk.Label(master=rebooting, text="Rebooting...", font=("", 15))
    label.pack()

    try:
        os.system("sudo teamviewer daemon stop")

    os.system("sudo teamviewer daemon start")

    label.configure(text"Rebooting Complete")
    sleep(1)
    rebooting.destroy()

    

    
rebootTeamViewer = tk.Button(master=root, text="Restart TeamViewer", command=None)
rebootTeamViewer.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

while this claims to work, as far as I can tell its not actually restarting TeamViewer.

Comment: `sudo` should ask you for password but `os.system()` will not ask you for password if you don't run it in console.

Comment: the user doesn't require a password for sudo commands, I tempered with the sudoers file.

Comment: I would rather use `gksudo` or `pkexec` to show window for password. It is more secure.

Comment: did you run your code in console to see error mesages ? You can't use `try` without `except` - so you should get error.

Comment: to restart you can use `restart` instead of `stop` and `start`. It will also start if deamon doesn't run.

Comment: I don't understant how did you expect it will work if you use `command=None`. Your button doesn't run `teamviewerReboot` so it can't restart it.

Answer (score 0):

First: your button has `command=None` so it never run any function so it can't reastart it.

Second: you can't use `try` without `except` or `finally` so you could get error if your button will run it.

Third: you need `time.sleep` instead of `sleep()

---

BTW: I would use `pkexec` instead of `sudo` to show window for password - it is more secure then running `sudo` without password.

Most deamons has option `restart` to restart it. It can also start deamon when it doesn't run. I don't have `teamviewer` to check if it also has this option.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import time

# --- functions ---

def teamviewer_reboot():

    rebooting = tk.Toplevel(root)

    label = tk.Label(rebooting, text="Rebooting...")
    label.pack()

    try:
        os.system("pkexec teamviewer daemon stop")
    except Exception as ex:
        print('ERROR:', ex)
    os.system("pkexec teamviewer daemon start")

    #os.system("pkexec teamviewer daemon restart")

    label.configure(text="Rebooting Complete")
    root.update() # update window because mainloop can't do this when sleep stops it.
    time.sleep(2)

    rebooting.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title(string="TeamViewerRebootButton")
root.geometry("200x200")

reboot_teamviewer = tk.Button(root, text="Restart TeamViewer", command=teamviewer_reboot)
reboot_teamviewer.pack()

root.mainloop()
```